# How to implement Checksum function while data inserting into table in ssis?

Tags: ssis

In my package after data inserted  into table. I have populated Checksum value through update query using SQL TASK it took more time . how to solve this With out third party component.

Kindly help me.

The below query to populate checksumID. In this table more 10 million records based on Import_Id.

UPDATE Communication SET ChecksumId = CHECKSUM(address1,address2,state,zip,city,....)
Where import_id=?

This process only take more time minimum 1 or 2 hours.

Comment: In my package after data inserted into table. I have populated Checksum value through update query using SQL TASK it took more time . how to solve this With out third party component.

Kindly help me.

Comment: You just pasted your original post as a comment to my question, that does not help me.

Comment: I have added few more points please find it

Comment: Can you include execution plan? Maybe the `where` clause makes it slow. Have you tried paritionning your table and have you created proper indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to code your own checksum function and apply it to each row of incoming data using a Script Transformation in the Data Flow which loads the data. That will probably fastest from an execution-time perspective; however, if it is essential that the value match the T-SQL CHECKSUM, you'll have a lot of reverse engineering to do.

Alternatively, instead of directly loading your target table, create a working table with the same layout as your target table, plus a computed column defined as CHECKSUM of the desired columns:

```
CREATE TABLE WRK_Communication
(
    address1 VARCHAR(50),
    address2 VARCHAR(50),
    -- other columns
    ChecksumId CHECKSUM(address1,address2,state,zip,city,....)    
)
```

In your SSIS package, first use an Execute SQL Task to truncate this working table, then use a Data Flow to load it, then use another Execute SQL task to insert the contents of the working table into your target table.

Comment: Thanks Edmund. Since the table having huge amount of data i'm not able to create working table with checksum. so, Is any othey way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the T-SQL CHECKSUM function : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx

You can use it on whole row, just like :

```
select FirstName, LastName, CheckSum(*) As CheckSum
  from SomeUserTable
```